# How to add values from one array of object to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, iteration

I'm trying to get a single Array with all values contained in arr1 and arr2. But I can't reach that final result.

```
arr1 = [
  {
    region: "Total",
    population: 15200100,
    first: 42999
  }
]

arr2 = [
  {
    region: "Total",
    second: 2939
  }
]

output = [
  {
    region: "Total",
    population: 15200100,
    first: 42999
    second: 2939
  }
]
```

Comment: um, btw in each arr all keys(things like `region`) **WILL** be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line:

```js
const arr1 = [ { region: "Total", population: 15200100, first: 42999 } ];
const arr2 = [ { region: "Total", second: 2939 } ];
const res = arr1.map((_, index) => ({ ...arr1[index], ...arr2[index] }));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const arr1 = [ { region: "Total", population: 15200100, first: 42999 } ];
const arr2 = [ { region: "Total", second: 2939 } ];
const res = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length || i < arr2.length; i++) {
  const first = arr1[i] || {};
  const second = arr2[i] || {};
  res[i] = { ...first, ...second };
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below returns a sum when similar keys are found.

```js
const arr1 = [{
  region: "Total",
  population: 15200100,
  first: 42999
}];
const arr2 = [{
  region: "Total",
  second: 2939
}];
const arr3 = [{
  region: "Total",
  population: 15200100,
  first: 42999
}];
const arr4 = [{
  region: "Total",
  first: 3243,
  second: 2939,
  third: 32
}];
function test(arr1,arr2) {
  let res = Array.from(arr1);
  res.forEach((x) => {
    arr2.forEach((y) => {
      for (let key in y) {
        if (typeof x[key] == 'undefined') {
          x[key] = y[key];
        } else {
          if (key !== 'region') {
            x[key] += y[key];
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
  return res;
}

console.log(test(arr1,arr2));
console.log(test(arr3,arr4));
```